# dist-upgrade broke the GUI

Tags: apt, upgrade, software-installation

I am on Ubuntu 21.10 with Wayland and Gnome 3.38.

This morning I ran `apt udate && apt dist-upgrade && apt autoremove`. Then I found I could no longer log in from my lock screen. On rebooting, I found that I wasn't even getting a GUI anymore.

I noticed that 8 packages were upgraded:

> libxfixes-dev libxfixes3 openjdk-11-jre openjdk-11-jre-headless php8.0-common php8.0-curl php8.0-gd php8.0-xml

However, apt also deemed a huge amount of packages as no longer required:

> glib-networking:i386 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386 gstreamer1.0-x:i386 libaa1:i386 libapparmor1:i386 libasound2:i386
> libasound2-plugins:i386 libasyncns0:i386 libavahi-client3:i386 libavahi-common-data:i386 libavahi-common3:i386
> libavc1394-0:i386 libbrotli1:i386 libcaca0:i386 libcairo-gobject2:i386 libcairo2:i386 libcapi20-3:i386
> libcdparanoia0:i386 libcups2:i386 libcurl3-gnutls:i386 libcurl4:i386 libdatrie1:i386 libdeflate0:i386 libdv4:i386
> libdw1:i386 libexif12:i386 libflac8:i386 libfontconfig1:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libfribidi0:i386 libgbm1:i386
> libgd3:i386 libgdbm-compat4:i386 libgdbm6:i386 libgdk-pixbuf-2.0-0:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 libglvnd0:i386
> libgnutls30:i386 libgphoto2-6:i386 libgphoto2-port12:i386 libgraphite2-3:i386 libgsm1:i386
> libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0:i386 libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 libgudev-1.0-0:i386
> libharfbuzz0b:i386 libhogweed6:i386 libiec61883-0:i386 libieee1284-3:i386 libjack-jackd2-0:i386 libjbig0:i386
> libjpeg-turbo8:i386 libjpeg8:i386 liblcms2-2:i386 libldap-2.5-0:i386 libltdl7:i386 libmp3lame0:i386 libmpg123-0:i386
> libnettle8:i386 libnghttp2-14:i386 libnspr4:i386 libnss3:i386 libodbc1:i386 libogg0:i386 libopenal1:i386
> libopenjp2-7:i386 libopus0:i386 liborc-0.4-0:i386 libosmesa6:i386 libp11-kit0:i386 libpango-1.0-0:i386
> libpangocairo-1.0-0:i386 libpangoft2-1.0-0:i386 libpcap0.8:i386 libpci3:i386 libperl5.32:i386 libpixman-1-0:i386
> libpng16-16:i386 libpoppler-glib8:i386 libpoppler111:i386 libproxy1v5:i386 libpsl5:i386 libpulse0:i386
> libraw1394-11:i386 librtmp1:i386 libsamplerate0:i386 libsane1:i386 libsasl2-2:i386 libsasl2-modules:i386
> libsasl2-modules-db:i386 libshout3:i386 libslang2:i386 libsndfile1:i386 libsndio7.0:i386 libsnmp40:i386
> libsoup2.4-1:i386 libspeex1:i386 libsqlite3-0:i386 libssh-4:i386 libstb0:i386 libtag1v5:i386 libtag1v5-vanilla:i386
> libtasn1-6:i386 libthai0:i386 libtheora0:i386 libtiff5:i386 libtwolame0:i386 libunwind8:i386 libusb-1.0-0:i386
> libv4l-0:i386 libv4lconvert0:i386 libvisual-0.4-0:i386 libvkd3d1:i386 libvorbis0a:i386 libvorbisenc2:i386 libvpx6:i386
> libwavpack1:i386 libwayland-cursor0:i386 libwayland-egl1:i386 libwayland-server0:i386 libwebp6:i386 libwrap0:i386
> libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcb-render0:i386 libxcb-shm0:i386 libxcb-xfixes0:i386 libxcomposite1:i386
> libxdamage1:i386 libxext6:i386 libxi6:i386 libxinerama1:i386 libxkbcommon0:i386 libxpm4:i386 libxrandr2:i386
> libxrender1:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 libxss1:i386 libxv1:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386 ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 steam-devices

The autoremove must've deleted these packages which look quite necessary for the GUI to run.

I was able to get the GUI back by running

```
apt install libxfixes3
apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

I just wonder why all these packages were suddenly deemed unnecessary?